# It's ok to make an http call in an observable or it's better something else?

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest

I made an http call inside an observable, do you think it is okay or should I split the two?

```
removeFav(movie:Movie){
this.getFavIdByMovie(movie).subscribe((data)=>{
  this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/favorites/${data[0].id}`).toPromise();
 });
}
```

another problem here is that i have a function with http request that return me an array of just 1 object and there is no possibility that return me more than 1 obj. How can i change the return into just the obj so in the first i can skip the data[0].id and write just data.id

```
getFavIdByMovie(movie:Movie){
  let userId = this.authSrv.getUserId();
  return this.http.get<Favorite>(`${this.baseURL}/favorites?userId=${userId}&movieId=${movie.id}`);
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine. By doing so you "chain" both calls, the second only start after the first finishes. Useful and even necesary to use the result of the first call in the second.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended to call an observable inside another's subscribe block. What you could do here is the following:

```
removeFav(movie: Movie) {
  return this.getFavIdByMovie(movie).pipe(
    switchMap((data) => this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/favorites/${data[0].id}`)
  )
}
```

Here, you are converting one stream into another through the use of `switchMap` operator. So you will have to subscribe to the `removeFave(movie)` stream to actually delete it (because unless you subscribe, it is in a cold state). An example usage:

```
onClickDelete() {
  this.removeFav(this.movie).subscribe({
    next: () => this.showAlert('Deleted');
  })
}
```

**Second part**
To unwrap a single object from the array of objects, you can use a `map` operator from RxJS.

```
getFavIdByMovie(movie: Movie): Observable<Favorite> {
  let userId = this.authService.getUserId();
  return this.http
    .get<Favorite>(`${this.baseURL}/favorites?userId=${userId}&movieId=${movie.id}`)
    .pipe(
       map((results) => results?.[0])
    )
}
```

Now, you will get a single object instead of an array.

Comment: thanks! i have another question, i have edited my question please check @TouhidRahman

Comment: @AlbertoDeMaria I have updated the answer to your second question.